# What breed was Walt Flanagan's dog (circa 1995)

Tags: dialogue, realism

There was a great line in Mallrats (one of many) that always stuck with me.  It was after Jay outruns the mallcop and remarks:

> "That dude is faster than Walt Flanagan's dog" 
> <sub>*[paraphrase]*</sub>

It had the ring of truth, and I started to notice Flanagan in the credits to Smith movies, confirming [he was a real person](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0281110/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1), almost certainly a friend of Smith's, which seems to be bourne out by Comic Book Men.

This leads me to believe that he had a dog that was remarkable in the neighborhood for its speed.  (Possibly it was a rescued greyhound?) This is something that has been nagging at me for years, so

**Q: What breed was Walt Flanagan's dog in the early 90's?**

Comment: There is a [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walt_Flanagan) dedicated to Walt Flanagan. Unfortunately, it doesn't mention what kind of dog he owns or owned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an image captioned "Walt Flanagan and Walt Flanagan’s Dog." which appears to be a small terrier<sup>*</sup> of some kind.

<sup>*</sup>Possibly a [Rat Terrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat_Terrier) (thanks to [@Malvolio](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/9071/malvolio))

[image]

<sup>[Source](http://silentbobspeaks.com/?p=170)</sup>

The reference is explained here: [**Den of Geek**](http://www.denofgeek.com/movies/18105/running-gags-and-inside-jokes-in-kevin-smiths-view-askewniverse)

> One of the more obscure references to Walt in the film comes when Jay and Silent Bob are on the run from security guard LaFours in Mallrats, and Jay says “Man, that bastard's faster than Walt Flanagan's dog.” This gag actually got its own comic spin-off, written by Smith, in which the dog gets stoned and chases the dynamic duo across New Jersey all night, leading directly into Mallrats.
>
> But the reference itself was explained on a 2010 episode of Highlands: A Peephole History, a show on Smith's Smodcast podcast network where he and his friends discuss their childhood and history in New Jersey. After quitting his behind-the-scenes job on Mallrats, Walt went and bought a dog, which he could only describe as “fast”.

This appears to be slightly different from the Comic Book version (where the dog "Brodie" had the name "Krypto").

[image]

Comment: Son, that is a [rat terrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat_Terrier).

Comment: Righteous, Paulie_D.  *"Hell hath no fury like a woman scorned for sega."*